# Div to JSON - AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have to make this div in JSON and I have a problem with background-image, for example. This is how it looks like in HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="bottom-1">
        <div class="icons">
            <img class="stick" src="images/sticker-white.png" />
            <p class="time">2' 22</p>
            <img class="play" src="images/play.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h6>XXX</h6>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom1-hover">
            <img class="stick" src="images/sticker-white.png" />
            <h6>XXX</h6>
            <h5 >Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor...</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottom-1
  position: relative
  display: inline-block
  height: 440px
  width: 360px
  float: left
  margin-right: 20px

  .icons
    position: relative
    background: url("../images/vid-block.jpg")
    background-size: cover
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: center center
    height: 225px

    .stick, .time, .play
      position: absolute
      right: 0%

    .stick
      margin-top: 20px
      margin-right: 20px

    .time
      margin-top: 130px
      margin-right: 23px
      color: white

    .play
      margin-top: 160px
      margin-right: 20px
      right: 0%

  .text
    background-color: white
    height: 215px
    overflow: hidden

    h6
      margin: 0
      font:
        size: 15px
        weight: 300
      padding-top: 32px
      padding-left: 40px

    p
      margin: 0
      font:
        size: 20px
        weight: 900
      letter-spacing: -0.2px
      padding-top: 3px
      padding-left: 40px
      padding-bottom: 25px

    ul
      display: block
      margin-bottom: 30px

      li
        display: inline
        list-style: none

        a
          text-decoration: none
          font:
            size: 14px
          color: #ec3b3a
          margin: 0 14px 0 0
          border-bottom: 1px solid
          padding-bottom: 6px

  .bottom1-hover
    visibility: hidden
    position: absolute
    background-image: url(../images/block-hover.jpg)
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center center
    top: 0%
    right: 0%
    bottom: 0%
    left: 0%

    .stick
      position: absolute
      right: 0%
      margin: 20px 20px

    h6, h5, ul, p
      position: absolute
      color: white
      bottom: 0%
      padding: 0 41px

    h6
      padding: 40px
      margin: 0
      font:
        size: 15px
        weight: 300
      margin-bottom: 314px

    h5
      padding: 40px
      font:
        size: 20px
        weight: 700
      margin-bottom: 240px

    p
      line-height: 26px
      padding-left: 40px
      padding-right: 0
      font:
        size: 15px
        weight: 300
      margin-bottom: 190px

    ul
      display: block
      margin: 0
      padding: 35px 41px 29px 39px

      li
        display: inline
        list-style: none
        margin-right: 9px

        a
          letter-spacing: -0.3px
          text-decoration: none
          border-bottom: 1px solid
          padding-bottom: 4px
          margin: 0
          color: #ee5560

  &:hover .bottom1-hover
    visibility: visible
```

Could you show me how to make this .bottom1 div in JSON? I have to do this, becouse I want to make filtering news by category and one guy helped me with this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/3bxcjdt7/4/

Comment: What do you mean "make this div in json"? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @mhatch I have to make div with class .bottom-1 in JSON and then load it to HTML

Comment: I don't understand your question either... Please explain it a bit more..